# Delete row in a vector

Tags: vector, delete-row

I try to delete a row from vector but it doesn't work, how should I do it?

```
for (vector<vector<Point>>::iterator iter = contours2.begin(); iter != contours2.end(); iter++)
{
    if ((*iter).size() < 20) 
    {   
        iter = contours2.erase(iter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete something from a list while you are iterating over it. Store what you want to delete in a variable and then delete it after the loop.